# Probability of the $5$ card hand contains the J and Q or J and 10

Tags: probability, statistics

$5$ cards are drawn randomly from the small deck (13 cards;one suit). The drawn cards are **not** placed back into the deck. What is the probability that the resulting five-card hand contains the Jack and the Queen or the hand contains the Jack and the 10?

I am having issues solving this one. I know that there are $13$ cards. And that pulling out $5$ cards gives an outcome of $1287$ combinations. Also I know that this is a without replacement problem.

Comment: How many hands contain both a Jack and $10$?

Comment: So the question asks that in the same hand what is the probability of having the Jack and the queen or also having the jack and 10

Comment: or is not while ...

Comment: The problem says "**small deck**", "**the 10**", "**the Jack**", and "**the Queen**".   Is a "small deck" a deck of 13 cards in one suit?

Comment: yes correct @GrahamKemp

Comment: Then there are not 52 cards.  There are 13.

Comment: Yes I later found out that mistake. @GrahamKemp could you offer some assistance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inclusion/Exclusion:

Start with the total number of hands: $\binom{52}{5}$

Exclude hands that do not contain at least one Jack: $\binom{48}{5}$

Exclude hands that do not contain at least one Queen or Ten: $\binom{44}{5}$

Include hands that contain none of Ten, Jack, Queen: $\binom{40}{5}$
(Because we excluded them twice)
$$\binom{52}{5}-\binom{48}{5}-\binom{44}{5}+\binom{40}{5}=458656$$

This is the number of qualifying hands. The probability of drawing one of these is:

$$\frac{458656}{2598960}=\frac{28666}{162435}\approx0.1765$$

For the case of only $13$ cards in the deck (one of each rank):
$$\binom{13}{5}-\binom{12}{5}-\binom{11}{5}+\binom{10}{5}=285$$
Probability:
$$\frac{285}{1287}=\frac{95}{429}\approx0.221445$$

Comment: Can i change it up for you and instead of assuming we use a full deck we only use 1 suit. S o in total we only have 13 cards total. 5 card Hand. And there is 1 jack, 1 queen, 1 number 10 card.

Comment: no exclusion of pairs of jacks ?

Comment: Well if we only have 13 cards of 1 suit. There is only 1 jack in this "Small Deck"

Comment: @Elchavo18 Done.

Comment: @DanielMathias Thank You! With the information you provided for the 52 cards i worked my way backwards to come to the same answer. Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

It is as easy as PIE (the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion).$$\mathsf P(A\cup B)=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)$$

The sample space contains $\binom{13}5$ equally probable ways to select five cards from the **small deck**, without replacement or bias.

There are $\binom {11}3$ ways to select the Jack, the Queen, and three other cards from the small deck.

Likewise there are $\binom{11}3$ ways to select the 10, the Jack, and three other cards from the small deck.

But wait!   We do not wish to over-count, and there are $\binom {10}2$ ways to select the 10, the Jack, and the Queen from the small deck.

Thus the probability for our favoured event is:$$\dfrac{2\binom {11}3-\binom {10}2}{\binom{13}5}$$

---

**Remark:** Using a small deck makes this easy. We do not have to worry about the possibility of pairs or such; there is only one card for each kind in the deck.